# PatchMapping returns 400 Status Springboot JPA MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, crud

I need help with my code, it's simple really but I don't understand how to resolve it as there are no errors in the code other than the 400 status return. My goal is just to use Patch in Postman to update the "cluster" for my "AnimalProfile" entity. The GET,POST,DEL are all working by the way.

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="animalProfile")
public class AnimalProfile {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private long animalProfileId;

   private String animalName;

   private String animalCluster;
```

Service

```
@Override
public void updateCluster(long animalProfileId, String animalCluster) {
    animalProfileRepository.updateCluster(animalProfileId, animalCluster);
}
```

Repository

```
public interface AnimalProfileRepository extends JpaRepository<AnimalProfile, Long> {
    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE AnimalProfile animalProfile SET 
    animalProfile.animalCluster=:animalCluster WHERE 
    animalProfile.animalProfileId=:animalProfileId")
    void updateCluster(@Param(value="animalProfileId") long animalProfileId,
                       @Param(value="animalCluster") String animalCluster);
}
```

Controller

```
@PatchMapping("/cluster/{animalProfileId}")
AnimalProfile updateAnimalCluster(@PathVariable Long animalProfileId,
                                         @RequestBody String animalCluster ) {
    animalProfileService.updateCluster(animalProfileId, animalCluster);
return animalProfileService.findById(animalProfileId);
}
```

Postman Request (PATCH)

```
{
    "animalCluster": "North Wing"
}
```

Postman Response

```
{
"timestamp": "2022-08-18T23:19:12.409+00:00",
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"path": "/webapp/animal/profile/cluster/1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following changes

Controller

```
@PatchMapping("/cluster/{animalProfileId}")
AnimalProfile updateAnimalCluster(@PathVariable Long animalProfileId,
                                     @RequestParam String animalCluster)
...
```

In postman, send the animalCluster as a Query Parameter since you're only updating just one value.

Something like this
[image]